# Bootstrap 3 - multiple active buttons in same btn-group

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Within a `<form>`, I have Bootstrap 3 button groups with radio buttons. I want to be able to have multiple buttons in the group be simultaneously active. What I mean is, in the fruit button group, someone should be able to click apples and then oranges and (1) have both stay active, (2) have the form send both values for that group.

Html so far looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <br><p>Click all the fruits that you like</p>
    <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="apple" id="apple" value="apple">apple
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="pear" id="pear" value="pear">pear
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="orange" id="orange" value="orange">orange
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried checkboxes, but I haven't gotten them to work. Figure there has to be a way...

Comment: why do you want to preventDefault ? Won't allow radio to be checked

Comment: I don't think radios will allow a user to un-check an option. Not sure if that matters to you.

Comment: The checkbox solution appears to work on the boostrap demo site

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Comment: @DeFeNdog Not sure I do want radio. But if I use `type="button"` I get two buttons. And I could not get the checkbox solution to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't use `radio` inputs for this, these are just for single selections within a group. For your needs you need `checkboxes`. Give them the same `name` tag value if they are in the same group and everything should work fine. All checked values will be send with the submit.

You can simply make it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <br><p>Click all the fruits that you like</p>
    <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="apple" value="apple">apple
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="pear" value="pear">pear
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="orange" value="orange">orange
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/FI7RVuwkEa)

Comment: In the bootply example, only one of the buttons is allowed to be active at a time. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Shamps indeed you are right, in the bootply the inputs were radios instead of checkboxes. I have no idea what happened that it was wrong. I corrected it now and updated the link..

Answer (score 0):

In HTML and most other design languages can only one button of a Radio Button group be clicked. If you want that more than one option can be clicked, you need **checkboxes**!
Here's an idea how you can use checkboxes:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <p>Fruits:</p>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="apple">apple
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="pear">pear
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="orange">orange
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If you like the radio button look, you can apply the radio buttons style to the checkboxes.

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use **checkbox**, its possible to style these with an image (*not illustrated*)

```
<div class="container">
<br><p>Click all the fruits that you like</p>
    <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="apple" id="apple" value="apple">apple
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pear" id="pear" value="pear">pear
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="orange" value="orange">orange
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can look this link us for styling checkboxes as radios http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/